# Initialising a reference to a class within a vector of pairs using a pointer to a pointer to an instance of that class

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

Apologies for the lengthy title, but I've noticed an odd behaviour that I can't understand regardless of the amount of testing I do.  I was hoping someone could shed some light on what's happening here and whether it's due to something I'm doing wrong.

I have created a vector 'v' of a custom class 'T', which I've populated with unique objects.  I want to use this vector as a sort of reference sheet.

I created a vector 'vp' of 'T' pointers, each element of which points to a specific unique element in 'v'.  I then shuffled 'vp' and created an iterator 'i' for it, meaning I could iterate through 'vp' and get the unique 'T's in a random order without modifying 'v'.

I then created a vector of pairs of type  with the intention of populating it with the randomised 'T's.  However what I found was that each time a new element was added to this vector of pairs, the values of T& all updated to the current value of 'i'.  What is the reason for this and (assuming that I must use this method) is there any way to avoid it?  The simplified code I've tried to describe is below:

```
std::vector<T> v{ ... }; //Contains list of unique 'T's
std::vector<T*> vp{};

for (std::vector<T>::const_iterator iElement = v.begin(); iElement < v.end(); ++iElement)
 vp.push_back(&(*iElement));

//Code for swapping elements of vp goes here

std::vector<std::pair<T&, int>> classVector{};
std::vector<T*>::iterator i{ vp.begin() };

for (int n = 0; n < 5; ++n)
{
 classVector.push_back(std::make_pair(**i, 1));
 ++i;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: had incorrectly used a for each loop to iterate through v, changed to iterator.

Comment: That is a ripper of a title ;-)

Comment: `for (T t : v)` that's making **temporary copies** of the objects in `v` and pointers to those will be invalidated immediately.

Comment: Thanks yes you're right.  I hit that problem when I was writing and after solving it promptly forgot, so when I came to write the example code I tried to simplify it.  I'll edit it and make a note.

Comment: It's better to compile the example code you post to make sure it displays the same error as your real code.

Comment: Good advice, I'll do that in future.

Comment: does this abstract code compile? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v{"111", "2222", "3333"};
    std::vector<const std::string*> vp;

    for (const auto& element : v) {
        vp.push_back(&element);
        std::cout << &element <<std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<std::pair<const std::string&, int>> classVector{};
    auto i = vp.begin();

    for (int n = 0; n < v.size(); ++n) {
        classVector.push_back(std::make_pair(**i, 1));
        std::cout << (**i) << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
    // prints same element
    for(const auto& e : classVector) {
        std::cout << (e.first) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is a compiled abstract c++11 sample code of what you are trying to do  and I will try to explain the problem on it. Basically you are pushing a pair to the vector to which this pair's first element is a reference to which ever string is pointed to by the iterator i (sorry for the wording complexity but what you are doing is complex and I don't get the point of it :) ). Taking the pointer is a different story, because pointers are copied (the addresses are copied not what's pointed to). so you go to the first element copy it's address, go the second copy it's address and so on. References are different!! The code above is taking the reference to any string that's pointed by the iterator so when the iterator moves on, the reference is refers to the string that i currently points to.